# How to Export HTML to Word Document with React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ms-word

Hello I have HTML data in my React App and want to export this in word document and download at button click event. can any one help to make this one please.

```
          let element = (
            <p  style={{fontSize: "10px", color:"#000"}}>
              Your investment in the maintenance package is just , billed directly to your credit card.
            </p>
           )

const generateDocx = async () => {
  const doc = new Document({
  sections: [
   {
     properties: {},
     children: [
       new Paragraph({
         children: [

           new TextRun(element),

         ],
       }),
     ],
   },
  ],
});

const blob = await Packer.toBlob(doc);
return blob;
};
```

how to save as .docx file instead of return blob

Comment: Do you develop a Word web add-in?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I am developing a web in React and want download reports as Word and PDF documents.

Comment: Use the Open XML SDK for generating Word documents in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Open XML SDK if you need to build Word documents on the fly. You may search for any libraries in JavaScript that allows creating Word documents like you could do using that SDK, see https://openxmldeveloper.org/. For example, you may find the [Creating OpenXML documents using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329526/creating-openxml-documents-using-javascript) post helpful.